# How do I print a specific field from an App Engine Search API document in a jinja2 template?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

I am using Google App Engine Search API (in Python) and I want to be able to print specific search_document fields in my jinja2 template. I am using this notation in the template to try to print the "comment" field of a search document:

`{{ scored_document.comment }}`

I want this output:

`test`

but instead I am getting this output:

`[search.TextField(name=u'comment', value=u'test')]`

What is the correct syntax for getting just the *value* of "comment"?

The [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/documentclass) seems to indicate that you can only get at this value through `.fields` member (a list object), but this notation doesn't seem to work either:

`{{ scored_document.fields.comment }}`

I am just extending the Search API sample provided by Google on [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-search-python-java/tree/master/python):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css"/>
    <title>Search Demonstration App</title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:20px;">

    <form action="/sign" method="post">
      <div>Search Demo</div>
      <div><textarea name="search" rows="1" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Search"/></div>
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Comment"/></div>
    </form>

    {{number_returned}} of {{results.number_found}} comments found <p>
    {% for scored_document in results %}

      <!-- Just want **value** of comment here: -->
      {{ scored_document.comment }}

      <p>
    {% endfor %}

    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont want to read all the code but try this <td>{{scored_document.get().message}}</td>

Comment: {{scored_document.get().comment}}

Comment: @peterretief I tried all possible combinations and the only one that worked for me was this and it is not optimal: `{{scored_document.fields.2.value|safe}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the 'value' property of the field:

```
{{ scored_document.comment.value }}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working. Nothing comes out. I've had some success with `{{scored_document.fields.5.value|safe}}` but it would be better to use a name and not an index.

Comment: Greg's answer doesn't work because the "comment" is an item in the "fields" list object. Niklas, you should post your `fields.#.value` solution as the answer to your question. It's the only solution I've found that actually works!

Comment: If iterating through a list of search result documents: {{ document.field('name').value }}